# android layout auto resize buttons to fill height

Tags: android, button, layout, scaling

I have 6 buttons inside a LinearLayout. The layout is centered.

Is it possible for the buttons to automatically resize in height so that each button is the same height but the total of all buttons combined (plus say a 10dp gap between them) equals the height of the layout.

I need to do this so if the app is used on a device with a bigger screen or a higher resolution it will scale the buttons to fill the layout.

Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Mark

EDIT CODE

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="420px"
            android:layout_height="99px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="clk_raynes"
            android:text="sitebutton"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50px" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rutlishbtn"
            android:layout_width="420px"
            android:layout_height="99px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="clk_rutlish"
            android:text="Site2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50px" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/harrisbtn"
            android:layout_width="420px"
            android:layout_height="99px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="clk_harris"
            android:text="Site3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50px" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="420px"
            android:layout_height="99px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="clk_ricards"
            android:text="Site4"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50px" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="420px"
            android:layout_height="99px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="clk_btn10"
            android:text="Site5"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50px" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="420px"
            android:layout_height="99px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="clk_btn11"
            android:text="Site6"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50px" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/picbtn3"

            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="190px"

            android:text="³"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="qrbtn" />

        </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `android:layout_height=0dp` and `android:layout_weight=1` in each button

I hope this help you!

Comment: please see edit above for my code it already had that in it but still wont change

Comment: Guys I got it to work but I have a problem with picbtn3 it needs to be square but when the height changes it becomes a rectangle as the width doesnt change. i need it to adjust the width to be the same as the height I understand I cant do this in the static xml but when I try to change the width in the activity i get a cannot cast to layout error any ideas

Comment: @user3422687 You can set programmatically the height and width of your button using:

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) picButton3.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;
picButton3.setLayoutParams(params);
`
If you show me the lines of code with the layout error I could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `android:layout_weight = 1` in your layout xml with your LinearLayout orientation set to vertical. Use margin on the buttons to create the gap you want.